# Can't Repair Mysql Table

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

I have one `ARCHIVE` table that I simply can't repair, I already try to remove the partitioning but still get this error:

```
alter table promo_tool_view_44 REMOVE PARTITIONING;
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'promo_tool_view_44'; try to repair it
```

I already try to repair the table but I get this reply:
repair table promo_tool_view_1;

```
+-----------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| Table                       | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                    |
+-----------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| vad_stats.promo_tool_view_1 | repair | error    | Partition p1 returned error |
| vad_stats.promo_tool_view_1 | repair | error    | Corrupt                     |
+-----------------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+

2 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: For ARCHIVE tables the only way I found to fix was to overwrite the table files, from one of the slave servers. But please guys if anyone as one solution for that please help us, to prevent future disasters!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For ARCHIVE tables the only way I found to fix was to overwrite the table files, from one of the slave servers. But please guys if anyone as one solution for that please help us, to prevent future disasters

Answer (score 2):

**If you have not done it yet: Shut down your DB and back it up. Repair operations are dangerous.**

Sad to say, I would strongly recommend a backup tape. Something is obviously broken in partition p1. But there are some tricks that might get your data back.

myisamchk implements lots of stuff not found in the cli. Try

```
myisamchk --safe-recover
myisamchk --recover
```

in that order and see if you have any more luck. There are plenty of flags that can help you. The full documentation can be found at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisamchk.html

The full documentation for repair in the cli can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html

Once you are done repairing you should track down why you got the DB corrupted in the first place. That's is not normal for MySQL databases.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use myisamchk because the tables are not MyIsam are in ARCHIVE

Comment: Then you are pretty much out of luck. Backups are a nice thing. You could also monitor this bug report which seems to be related http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46565

Comment: I have buckups in several slaves, I was able to restore info, but it will be nice to know one way to restore ARCHIVE tables after corruption.