# Before repair with myisamchk, do "mysqladmin shutdown" first or backup database first?

Tags: mysql, backup, database

This is Drupal 6 `cache` table. Server version: 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (Ubuntu)

According to [Can't Repair Mysql Table](https://serverfault.com/questions/120277/cant-repair-mysql-table/120300#120300)

> Shut down your DB and back it up.
>   Repair operations are dangerous.

but according to http://www.techrepublic.com/article/checking-and-repairing-mysql-tables/5193721

> The first—and most important—thing you
>   can do before repairing a corrupted
>   table is to back it up.
>   
>   Next, shut down the MySQL server.

I've tried what techrepublic says... but I got this message from mysqlhotcopy:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Table './dbname/cache' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed at /usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy line 460.
```

and I got this message from mysqldump:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `cache`': Table './dbname/cache' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed (144)
```

Comment: If it's just a cache table, just drop it and re-create the table. It'll get automatically re-populated as the site is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stop the MySQL server then you should be able to take a backup of the database files from `/var/lib/mysql/databasename` which you could restore if there is a problem with the repair and you cannot take a proper backup via `mysqldump`